# How to select only images with tags

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have the following tables set up

**ImageTags |** `ImageID, TagID`

**Images |** `ID, Name, Path`

**Tags |** `ID, Tag, Count`

I linked the `IDs` of the images to the `IDs` of the tags in **code**, and put that in **ImageTags**.

Is there a way to use **sqlite** commands to select only the images linked to certain tags?

I can do it using code ofc, but was expecting there to be a simple way to do so directly using sql, but I can't figure out how :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do something like this?

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Images i
INNER JOIN ImageTags it ON i.ID = it.ImageID
INNER JOIN Tags t on t.ID = it.TagID
WHERE t.Tag = "yourtagname";
```